# Double dropdown menu not showing the second dropdown

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, menu

The first dropdown is working normally, but the second I can not make it work at all. I have tried to specify more the classes, but does not work, I believe it is something very simple that I am passing unnoticed. I'll be grateful if someone help me.

The dropdown I say is in the "Other Consoles" menu, it was to show the div with the class "dropdown-content-2" when hovering the "a" tag with the "drop-secundario" class.

```css
.header-menu {
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-menu ul li {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-menu ul li.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
  padding: 0 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: block;   
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #ff0000;
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 180px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 70px;
}

.arrow-down:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 6px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}

/*Dropdown 2*/

.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario:hover .dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">PS4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">XBOX ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">eSports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lançamentos</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="arrow-down">Mais</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="drop-secundario">Outros Consoles</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content-2">
    <a href="#">PS3</a>
    <a href="#">XBOX 360</a>
    <a href="#">Switch</a>
    <a href="#">WII U</a>
    <a href="#">3DS</a>
    <a href="#">PS Vita</a>
    <a href="#">Retrô</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Autores</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector of your last CSS rule to this:

```
.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario:hover+.dropdown-content-2
```

The reason for this: `.dropdown-content-2` is not a child of `a.drop-secundario`, but its sibling, therefore the "+" in that selector.

```css
.header-menu {
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header-menu ul li {
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header-menu ul li.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-menu ul li a {
  padding: 0 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: block;   
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-menu ul li:hover {
  background: #ff0000;
}

/*Dropdown Menu*/

.dropdown-content {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ff0000;
  width: 180px;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.header-menu ul li .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 70px;
}

.arrow-down:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 6px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
}

/*Dropdown 2*/

.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0fa;
  width: 200px;
  right: 180px;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}
.dropdown-content .dropdown-content-2:hover,
.dropdown-content a.drop-secundario:hover+.dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">PS4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">XBOX ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">eSports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lançamentos</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="arrow-down">Mais</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="drop-secundario">Outros Consoles</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content-2">
    <a href="#">PS3</a>
    <a href="#">XBOX 360</a>
    <a href="#">Switch</a>
    <a href="#">WII U</a>
    <a href="#">3DS</a>
    <a href="#">PS Vita</a>
    <a href="#">Retrô</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Autores</a>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but now i'm having trouble with another thing, i changed the "dropdown-content-2" to show on the left side, but it's showing only when i hover the "drop-secundario", so i cant navigate in the left menu. Code:                                                                                                                                                                                .dropdown-content-2 {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
}

Comment: I made changes to the last two rules in my snippet: I added another selector and adjusted the position of the second dropdown. You can adjust the position and width values if necessary.

Comment: It worked, thanks, but the !important is not needed, change that and i accept your answer

Comment: yes, that was a leftover from trying around which I forgot to erase again... (edited now)